# Subtract columns from two DFs based on matching condition

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following two DFs:

*DF A*: First column is a date, and then there are columns that start with a year (2021, 2022...)

```
Date    2021.Water  2021.Gas    2022.Electricity
may-04      500       470         473
may-05      520       490         493
may-06      540       510         513
```

*DF B*: First column is a date, and then there are columns that start with a year (2021, 2022...)

```
Date    2021.Amount 2022.Amount
may-04       100         95
may-05       110        105
may-06       120        115
```

The **expected result** is a DF with the columns from DF A, but that have the rows divided by the values for the matching year in DF B. Such as:

```
Date    2021.Water  2021.Gas    2022.Electricity
may-04       5.0       4.7           5.0 
may-05       4.7       4.5           4.7 
may-06       4.5       4.3           4.5
```

I am really struggling with this problem. Let me know if any clarifications are needed and will be glad to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
dfai = dfa.set_index('Date')
dfai.columns = dfai.columns.str.split('.', expand=True)

dfbi = dfb.set_index('Date').rename(columns = lambda x: x.split('.')[0])

df_out = dfai.div(dfbi, level=0).round(1)
df_out.columns = df_out.columns.map('.'.join)
df_out.reset_index()
```

Output:

```
     Date  2021.Water  2021.Gas  2022.Electricity
0  may-04         5.0       4.7               5.0
1  may-05         4.7       4.5               4.7
2  may-06         4.5       4.2               4.5
```

***Details***

First, move 'Date' into the index of both dataframes, then use string split to get years into a level in each dataframe.

Use, pd.DataFrame.div with level=0 to align operations on the top level index of each dataframe.

Flatten multiindex column header back to a single level and reset_index.

Comment: Fantastic!  Similar direction that I was going.  But I just stopped after this (-:

Comment: @piRSquared Please feel free to edit or update this solution if you have a better way?  Using pd.DataFrame.align perhaps?  Or heck... go ahead and put your solution here.  I don't care about points.  I just want to learn.

Comment: Your way is less verbose.  I was messing with `set_axis` instead of `rename`.  No functional difference.

Comment: Amazing, thank you. I wish some day I get to this python & problem-solving level!